# Check if value is exist in database jQuery and php

Tags: php, html, jquery

I m having a bit of trouble while validating value in database.
This is my html and js Code:

```
    <input type="text" name="Unieke-voucher" value="" size="40" maxlength="8" minlength="8"  id="voucher" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="XYZ 1234">
    var searchTimeout; //Timer to wait a little before fetching the data
    jQuery("#voucher").keyup(function() {
        vCode = this.value;
        
        clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    
        searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            getUsers(vCode);    
        }, 400); //If the key isn't pressed 400 ms, we fetch the data
    });
    var searchTimeout; //Timer to wait a little before fetching the data
jQuery("#voucher").keyup(function() {
    vCode = this.value;
    
    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        getUsers(vCode);    
    }, 400); //If the key isn't pressed 400 ms, we fetch the data
});
function getUsers(vCode) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'voucher.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {value: vCode},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status) {
                            jQuery("#codeError").html('');
                                console.log(data);
            } else {
                            jQuery("#codeError").html('Value not found');
            }   
                        console.log(data);  
        }
                
    });     
}
```

With this getting value with keyup event and sending to php script till here working fine.
And this is php script:

```
$dbname = "voucher";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "root";
$dbhost = "localhost";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$voucherCode = $_GET['VoucherCode'];
$voucherCode['status'] = false;
//echo $voucherCode;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM VoucherCode WHERE `code` LIKE '$voucherCode' LIMIT 1");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
  $userData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  $voucherCode['code'] = $Code;
  $voucherCode['status'] = true;            
}

echo json_encode($voucherCode);
```

I am always getting status value even providing correct value.
When i print_r table like

```
$resultAll = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM VoucherCode");
 $data2 = mysqli_fetch_all($resultAll);
 print_r($data2);
```

I am able to see all data is there.
I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. Can anyone help me with this please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `$voucherCode` is an array, but you building query `WHERE code LIKE '$voucherCode'` (which probably results with  `WHERE code LIKE 'Array'` - did you debug it at all???

Comment: BTW **Warning!!!** Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).